# What determines a Python Flask project version?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Python and couldn't find this answer online.

When creating a Python Flask application, what exactly determines the Python version used? I inherited an existing Python Flask application that is currently version 3.6 and wanted to upgrade it to a newer version.

Is this as simple as changing the Python version that is installed on the environment that runs the Python application or is the specific version defined in a project file?

I have tried updating the version of Python in my local environment but the project version did not change.

Comment: Is the project using some venv(virtual environment) ?

Comment: create a vrtual env with python 3,8, go into the virtual env python shell, install all the package for the current project from requiremet.txt and run the flask server

Comment: @anon_143 Yes, this project is run in a venv. Is that where the version is defined?

Comment: You go inside that venv(if you have installed) or create one and then alter the python version inside that venv. Venv's are very good if you don't want to alter versions in your local pc.

Answer (score 0):

What you might have right now is python3 corresponding to 3.6 and python corresponding to 2.x.

You could install a new version of python; in this case 3.8 by downloading it from python website [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and install it as python3.8 instead of replacing python3 or python.

Once installed, you could run virtual env with the -p or --python and passing the path to the executable as the argument as follows

`python3.8 -m venv path/for/venv/py3.8`

Once it's set up, source it and check out the python version.

Answer (score 0):

> what exactly determines the Python version used?

You can write whichever Python style you want in the project (2.x or 3.x) as long as it is supported for the version of Flask you are using.

What "determines" the version it executes with is which version of Python you specify when you start Flask. As in "python app.py" or "python3 app.py" will start with either version etc.